# Retrieving CTreeCtrl items after closing the Dialog

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

In an application I am required to only process the items selected in a tree. I am using MFC CTreeCtrl in a property sheet added to a Dailog. The tree shows a list of folders, the user selects some and when the user presses OK, I need to process the folders. I save the folder information by using SetItemData. Everything else is working fine. The problem is that when the user presses OK, the CTreeCtrl variable gets null and therefore i cannot use GetItemData. Is there a way that i still use the variable even after its dialog is closed?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transfer the information into another variable, that will exist when the window will be destroyed. For a list of folders, a `std::vector<CString>` is a good solutions.

Inside the dialog, when the user presses ok, go through your tree and copy the folder paths into the vector.

Outside the dialog, the code looks something like this:

```
CMyDlg dlg(this);
if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    // Information is in dlg.m_vecFolders available
}
```